# Merging three different customer segmentation systems into one

Tags: classification, r, clustering

I have been given a task where I have three existing customer segmentation systems (rule based e.g. if customer spends X in Y amount of time AND whatever then put in top spender segment is one segment, another is measured on metrics such as time spent on the site, etc and the last one is the lifetime loyalty segmentation system).
I have been asked to merge into one customer segmentation system.
I would like to ask your opinion or sources of information to decide whether I keep this rule based system (maybe a point based system) or use another method such as clustering. They want it to be flexible, thus be able to add additional layers as time goes by. They must be able to cater for different markets, which have different 'rules'

DO you believe I should keep the rule based system? Use clustering? What are the disadvantages of merging all three current customer segmentation systems?

Comment: Hi @Lilz ! What is the main motivation behind the merge?Is it more insight? Less complexity? Perhaps financially motivated?

Comment: because some of the clients are being marked in totally different categories, e.g. most loyal customer in one group but hardly relevant in another. they want something that summarizes and puts the user in one group

Comment: So would it be right to say that some of the rules don't produce the desired result?Is there a sense that one set is superior, or would your job also include improving the overall grouping? And if so, would you have anything to guide the grouping (some form of truth).

Comment: Yes. Some are superior. WOuld you use a point system? where each rule has a certain value attached to it?

Answer (score 1):

You are supposedly supposed to *merge* the existing three systems.

I think it is a fairly safe bet they don't want you to add a fourth, that is *unstable* in the sense that as data changes, segments will change.

Comment: so i should probably avoid clustering.